# Сформировать url из массива JS

Tags: javascript

Есть массив параметров, как можно сформировать из него url параметры: "index.php?param1=value1&param2=value2"

http://jsfiddle.net/IVsevolod/f9eJv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ

```
var arrStr = '{"filter_name":"","filter_rdate":"","filter_number":"","filter_theme":"12","filter_project":"23","filter_product":"45","filter_job":"67","filter_description":"78","filter_comment":"","filter_planned":"","filter_actual":""} ';

var url = arrStr.replace(/['"\{\}]/g, '').replace(/:/g, '=').replace(/,/g, '&');

alert('index.php?' + url);
```

Answer (score 1):

У `jQuery` есть такой метод:

```
$.param(obj);
```

Или как-нибудь так:

```
serialize = function(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for(var p in obj) {
        str.push(p + "=" + obj[p]);
    }
    return str.join("&");
}
```

Не забудьте про функции, такие как [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) и другие.